# Why this wp_redirect function is not working?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to do a redirection inside my plugin, I want to send the user directly to the edit post page, instead it is redirecting to the post list.

```
wp_redirect( get_edit_post_link( $post_id ) ); exit;
```

For your information, get_edit_post_link() is returning the right value: http://localhost/wp-admin/post.php?post=63&action=edit.

Answer (score 5):

If someone is still looking for this, try:

```
wp_redirect( get_edit_post_link( $post_id, '' ) ); exit;
```

From WP docs:

> context (string) (optional) How to write ampersands. Defaults to
>   'display' which will encode as '&'. Passing any other string
>   (including an empty string), will encode ampersands as '&'. Default:
>   'display'

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why `get_edit_post_link` doesn't play nice within `wp_redirect`, but if you pass the edit post link path to `admin_url` it works:

`wp_redirect( admin_url( '/post.php?post=' . get_the_ID() . '&action=edit' ) ); exit;`

Answer (score 0):

Check the role of the user you are testing with.

If its author, an author / contributor cannot edit other's post.